# Counting subsequent letters

Tags: python, string, frequency, letter, frequency-distribution

So I am trying to implement code that will count the next letter in a sentence, using python. 
so for instance,

```
"""So I am trying to implement code that will count the next letter in a sentence, using 
python"""
```

most common letters one after the other

1. for 's'

   - 'o' :1
   - 'e' :1
2. for 'o'

   - ' ' :1
   - 'd' :1
   - 'u' :1
   - 'n' :1

I think you get the idea

I already have written code for counting letters prior

```
def count_letters(word, char):
    count = 0
    for c in word:
        if char == c:
            count += 1
    return count
```

As you can see this just counts for letters, but not the next letter. can someone give me a hand on this one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Markov chain on letter scale and random text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660015/markov-chain-on-letter-scale-and-random-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(Counter)

s = """So I am trying to implement code that will count the next letter in a sentence, using
python""".lower()

for c1, c2 in zip(s, s[1:]):
    counts[c1][c2] += 1
```

(apart from being simpler, this should be significantly faster than pault's answer by not iterating over the string for every letter)

Concepts to google that aren't named in the code:

- `for c1, c2 in ...` (namely the fact that there are two variables): tuple unpacking
- `s[1:]`: slicing. Basically this is a copy of the string after the first character.

Comment: Looks good. I will add here some further reading: [Understanding python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation) and [Zip lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704860/zip-lists-in-python)

Comment: Oh, wow... The `defaultdict` is definitely something I should add to my toolbox. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `collections.Counter`:

Suppose the string you provided was stored in a variable `s`.

First we iterate over the set of all lower case letters in `s`. We do this by making another string `s_lower` which will convert the string `s` to lowercase. We then wrap this with the `set` constructor to get unique values.

For each `char`, we iterate through the string and check to see if the previous letter is equal to `char`. If so, we store this in a list. Finally, we pass this list into the `collections.Counter` constructor which will count the occurrences.

Each counter is stored in a dictionary, `counts`, where the keys are the unique characters in the string.

```
from collections import Counter

counts = {}
s_lower = s.lower()
for char in set(s_lower):
    counts[char] = Counter(
        [c for i, c in enumerate(s_lower) if i > 0 and s_lower[i-1] == char]
    )
```

For your string, this has the following outputs:

```
>>> print(counts['s'])
#Counter({'i': 1, 'e': 1, 'o': 1})

>>> print(counts['o'])
#Counter({' ': 2, 'd': 1, 'n': 1, 'u': 1})
```

One caveat is that this method will iterate through the whole string for each unique character, which could potentially make it slow for large lists.

---

Here is an alternative approach using `collections.Counter` and `collections.defaultdict` that only loops through the string once:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

def count_letters(s):
    s_lower = s.lower()
    counts = defaultdict(Counter)
    for i in range(len(s_lower) - 1):
        curr_char = s_lower[i]
        next_char = s_lower[i+1]
        counts[curr_char].update(next_char)
    return counts

counts = count_letters(s)
```

We loop over each character in the string (except the last) and on each iteration we update a counter using the next character.

Comment: The first test case should be `Counter({'o': 1, 'e': 1, 'i': 1})`. You're missing `'o'`.

Comment: Also `set(map(str.lower, s))` can just be `set(s.lower())`

Comment: @AlexHall good catch. I forgot one `.lower()`. Edited now. Also good point about the `set(s.lower()`.

Comment: So, it will run tens or even hundreds of times through the entire text? Once for every character?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I didn't say it was the *best* solution.

Comment: Call .lower once and store the result.

Comment: @pault I didn't claim it was "the worst" either ;) My own solution uses unnecessary `O(n * log(n))`-sorting just so I don't have to reimplement a `groupby` that doesn't rely on the order, so it's not the most efficient solution either...

Comment: @AndreyTyukin added a second method that should be more efficient. Only once through the string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a relatively terse way to do it:

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import Counter

def countTransitionFrequencies(text):
  prevNext = list(zip(text[:-1], text[1:]))
  prevNext.sort(key = lambda pn: pn[0])
  transitions = groupby(prevNext, lambda pn: pn[0])
  freqs = map(
    lambda kts: (kts[0], Counter(map(lambda kv: kv[1], kts[1]))), 
    transitions
  )
  return freqs
```

Explanation:

1. `zip` creates list of pairs with `(previous, next)` characters
2. The pairs are sorted and grouped by the `previous` character
3. The frequencies of the `next` characters (extracted from pairs by `kv[1]`) are then counted using `Counter`.

Sorting is not really necessary, but unfortunately, this is how the provided `groupby` works.

An example:

```
for k, v in countTransitionFrequencies("hello world"):
  print("%r -> %r" % (k, v))
```

This prints:

```
' ' -> Counter({'w': 1})
'e' -> Counter({'l': 1})
'h' -> Counter({'e': 1})
'l' -> Counter({'l': 1, 'o': 1, 'd': 1})
'o' -> Counter({' ': 1, 'r': 1})
'r' -> Counter({'l': 1})
'w' -> Counter({'o': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, the only thing is it doesn't sort the values, but that can be solved by creating a new dictionary with list of tuples (char, occurrences) and using sorted function on tuple[1].

```
def countNext(word):
    d = {}
    word = word.lower()
    for i in range(len(word) - 1):
        c = word[i]
        cc = word[i+1]
        if(not c.isalpha() or not cc.isalpha()):
            continue
        if c in d:
            if cc in d[c]:
                d[c][cc] += 1
            else:
                d[c][cc] = 1
        else:
            d[c] = {}
            d[c][cc] = 1
    return d
```